Django connect to remote Postgres: '127.0.0.1 works while 'localhost' fails
I set up local port forwarding to remote server on which a Postgres db is running.
ssh -v -L 127.0.0.1:5433:localhost:5432 user@server-ip

My django settings:
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '<db_name>',
        'USER': '<db_user>',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}

When I run server, I got error as below:

Error occurred during checks: OperationalError('connection failed: :1), port 5433 failed: could not receive data from server: Connection refused\ncould not send startup packet: Connection refused')

I wanted to identify if the connection issue comes from client or server side, so I tried to connect to the db by psql:
psql <db_name> -U <db_user> -p 5433 -h localhost

and it works !!! So I guessed it was client issue.
The django server could only connect to the db only when I changed 'HOST': 'localhost' to 'HOST': '127.0.0.1'
My /etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1   postgres
127.0.0.1   mysql
127.0.0.1   redis

pg_hba.conf:
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by saritasa
127.0.0.1   postgres
127.0.0.1   mysql
127.0.0.1   redis
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
127.0.0.1 mysql
127.0.0.1 redis

I can't connect from my django local server if HOST is set to localhost but it works if replaced by 127.0.0.1
May you guys give me some insights ? Thanks
